# Solving the warning in compiler: Sending 'BarCodeViewController *_strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<PerksDetailsDelegate>'

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, delegates

I have 2 view controllers, `PerksDetailsViewController` and `BarcodeViewController`. I used delegation to pass a `Card` class and points of a perk from PerksDetailsVC to BarcodeVC.

My app works, however I want to get rid of this warning: `Sending 'BarCodeViewController *_strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<PerksDetailsDelegate>'`

which comes from the line `[self setDelegate:barCodeVC];`

inside the method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showBarCode"]) {
        BarcodeViewController *barCodeVC = (BarcodeViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

        [self setDelegate:barCodeVC];

    }
}
```

Below is some more codes that could be helpful to find the part that's wrong

PerksDetailsViewController.m

```
#import Card.h
#import PerksDetailsViewController.h
#import BarcodeViewController.h

@interface PerksDetailsViewController () 

@end

@implementation
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
@synthesize myCard = _myCard;

- (IBAction)redeemPressed:(id)sender {
    // get required points of a perk selected

     NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
     [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

     self.pointsRequired = [f numberFromString: (self.pointsLabel.text)];

    NSLog(@"points required by the perk %@", self.pointsRequired);

    [self.delegate perksDetailsViewController:self didPassRequiredPoints:self.pointsRequired withCard:self.myCard];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showBarCode"]) {
        BarcodeViewController *barCodeVC = (BarcodeViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;

        [self setDelegate:barCodeVC];

    }
}

@end
```

PerksDetailsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Card.h"
#import "BarcodeViewController.h"

@class PerksDetailsViewController;

@protocol PerksDetailsDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)perksDetailsViewController:(PerksDetailsViewController *)sender
             didPassRequiredPoints: (NSNumber *) requiredPoints
                          withCard: (Card *) selectedCard;

@end

@interface PerksDetailsViewController : UIViewController 

@property (nonatomic, strong) id <PerksDetailsDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, strong) Card *myCard;

@end
```

BarcodeViewController.m

```
#import "PerksDetailsViewController.h"

@interface BarcodeViewController () <PerksDetailsDelegate>
@end

@implementation BarcodeViewController
@synthesize myCard = _myCard;
@synthesize resultingPoints = _resultingPoints;

- (void)perksDetailsViewController:(PerksDetailsViewController *)sender didPassRequiredPoints:(NSNumber *)requiredPoints withCard:(Card *)selectedCard 
{

    double perksPoints = [requiredPoints doubleValue];

        self.myCard = selectedCard;
        self.resultingPoints = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[selectedCard subtractPoints:perksPoints] ];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .h implementation of BarCodeViewController you need to tell the compiler that you implement the  protocol.

```
@interface BarCodeViewController : UIViewController <PerksDetailsDelegate> {
...
}
```

Comment: Ok, so I moved the `#import PerksDetailsViewController.h` and `<PerksDetailsDelegate>` from BarcodeVC.m to BarcodeVC.h. Yet, now not just an error appeared but an error saying "Cannot find protocol declaration for 'PerksDetailsDelegate'".

Comment: If it's declared in PerksDetailsViewController.h and you have included that file, it makes no sense that it says it can't find it. Are you sure it's not a misspelling? Or perhaps try a Clean?

Comment: No it's not misspelled. What about clean?

Comment: Try removing <NSObject> from your protocol definition. I am not sure why that is there. Then your protocol should be defined in PerksDetailsViewController.h and when you import it in BarcodeViewController.h it should find it.

Comment: Removing the `<NSObject>` seems not to affect anything bad on the app. I imported PerksDetailsViewController.h in my BarcodeViewController.h and did the same thing as your original answer. However, I still get the same error I've stated on my first comment here.